# Div not taking full width of children

Tags: html, css

I want to position two `div` elements side by side with flexbox.

Inside my `div` elements I have a `label` with an `absolute` positioning and a `span`. My problem is that the `div` elements are not taking the full width of the `label` if the `label` has a bigger width than the span. How can I make sure that the `div` elements are taking the full width of its children?

**Minimal example**:
http://jsfiddle.net/khbg9w50/2/

```css
#flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container {
  width: auto;
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.4);
}

.label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  font-size: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<div id="flex-container">
  <div class="container">
    <label class="label">A Very, Very Long Labeltext</label>
    <span>Example 1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <label class="label">A Very, Very Long Labeltext</label>
    <span>Example 2</span>
  </div>
</div>https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55665051/edit#
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You know what ID means? It should be unique. Use `class` instead. `class="container"`, `class="label"` etc...

Comment: I'm not sure why you use absolute positioning at all, and what's the expected result - so, hard to point you straight away to the best solution...

Comment: id is used as a unique identifier. you should be using a class for your container

Comment: Sorry, it was a mistake I did when setting up the minimal example. I updated the question.

Comment: A _reproducible sample_ should be **within the question**, not as an external link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely positioned elements sit outside of the normal page flow meaning that if a child element has an absolute value then the parent element will behave as if the child isn’t there at all.

I see no reason to use `position:absolute` in your example code. Simply make the labels `display:block`. Or, if you need the labels to remain at their natural width, make the `span {display:block;}` instead.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container {
  width: auto;
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.4);
}

.container label {
  /* display:block; */
  font-size: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
.container span {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="container">
    <label>A Very, Very Long Labeltext</label>
    <span>Example 1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <label>A Very, Very Long Labeltext</label>
    <span>Example 2</span>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <label>A short one</label>
    <span>Example 3</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

PS. [`id` must be unique.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id)

**UPDATE**

I realise now that you may not want all of your labels to be full width (for example in the case of short labels. If that is the case it would make more sense to set the `span` as display:block rather than the label. I've updated my answer accordingly.